# Number of onto and into group homomorphisms between $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z$

Tags: group-theory

How many homomorphisms are there of

1. $\mathbb Z$ onto $\mathbb Z$
2. $\mathbb Z$ into $\mathbb Z$

These two questions are from exercise 13, from book by John B. Fraleigh.

Answer of 1. is "two homomorphisms" and 2. is "infinite number of homomorphisms". I want to know difference between these, how to approach these problems.

Comment: Group homomorphism, ring homomorphism, or something else?

Comment: Group homomorphisms

Comment: As a group ${\Bbb Z}=<1>$. Thus any group homomorphism $\phi:{\Bbb Z}\rightarrow{\Bbb Z}$ is determined by $\phi(1)\in\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 9):

Note that a homomorphism from $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow G$ to another group $G$ is completely determined by where it maps $1$. Indeed, take $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $f(n) = f(1+\cdots+1) = f(1)+\cdots+f(1) = nf(1)$. Now suppose we want a surjective homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$. Then some element must be mapped to $1$. Suppose $|f(1)|>1$. Then $|f(n)| = n|f(1)|>n$, so if we want surjectiveness we must have $|f(1)|\le 1$. The only options left are $-1,0,1$. Check that only two of these work. Can you do the injective part yourself now?

Comment: I dont know what u r writing, is that order of f(1) cannot be more than 1?

Comment: $f(1) = 0 $ is a trivial homomorphism ,not epi. So $f(1)=1 \ \text {or} -1$

Comment: There is another question for number of homomorphisms of Z into$ Z_2$. Here answer given is 2 namely $\phi (1)$=0, and $ \phi (m)$=r where r is remainder given by division algo when m is divided by n. But are not these 2 homomorphisms many one?

Comment: It means the absolute value

Answer (score 5):

If $f\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is a group homomorphism, then, setting $n=f(1)$, you have
$$
f(x)=nx
$$
for every $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ (prove it). So the image of $f$ is $n\mathbb{Z}$ and it should be clear for what $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $n\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$.

For $f$ being injective you need $\ker f=\{0\}$; but
$$
\ker f=\{x\in\mathbb{Z}:nx=0\}
$$
Can you finish?

For the final counting, note that, when you fix $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, the map $x\mapsto nx$ is a homomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3):

Just rewriting other people's answers. Let's say that $f(1) = m$ (it's gotta be something and I am just calling that something $m$, so I haven't made any assumptions yet).

I claim we know $f$ on the nose just from this data of $m$. Indeed, $f(2) = f(1 + 1) = 2m$, $f(3) = f(1 + 1 + 1) = 3m$, etc. It's clear that $f(n) = nm$ for $n$ positive (you can prove this by induction if you are feeling excessively formal). I'll leave it to you to prove this for $n$ negative (which is true).

So we have a formula for $f(n)$ automatically, just in terms of $f(1)$. (And conversely, this formula determines a homomorphism, so anything can be $f(1)$). This answers the second question. To see which ones are "onto," consider when $1$ can be in the image. That says that $1 = mn$ for some $n$. Since $m$ and $n$ are integers, the only possibilities are $m = n = -1$ and $m = n = 1$. That answers the first question (if $1$ is in the image, anything is in the image -- do you see why?).

Answer (score 3):

For the onto case
since $1$ is a generator of the cyclic group $(Z,+)$, $f(1)$ is also a generator of the image group $Z$. Now there are only two generators of $Z$ and they are $1$ and $-1$. So either $f(1)=1$ or $f(1)=-1$.
If $f(1)=1$, then $f(n)=n$ for all $n$.
If $f(1)=-1$ then $f(n)=-n$ for all $n$.
Thus there are only two homomorphisms

Answer (score 0):

An onto homomorphism $f$ has the additional requirement that the image of $f$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ itself.