# How to understand "unique" for universal properties

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.09375) basic text on Category Theory. The author presents the concept of a universal property early, and I'm wondering about one of the examples. The author writes

> **Example 0.2** This example involves rings, which in this book are always taken to have a multiplicative identity, called $1$. Similarly,
>   homomorphisms of rings are understood to preserve multiplicative
>   identities. The ring $\mathbb{Z}$ has the following property: for all rings $R$,
>   there exists a unique homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to R$

The author then proceeds with a construction of the claimed homomorphism, and states that this is a universal property for rings, in the sense that if this property is satisfied for any ring $R$ then $\mathbb{Z} \cong R $

I'm not sure how to feel about this, because, taken at face value, it seems that is states that $\mathbb{Z}$ has the property that, given any other ring $R$, there exists one and only one homo $\mathbb{Z} \to R$, but this is not true! Taking $R = \mathbb{Z}$, this is not true by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1117488/number-of-onto-and-into-group-homomorphisms-between-mathbb-z-and-mathbb-z?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) question.

Maybe the author means something else? Or how does this work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a unique homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to R$ for any ring $R$. The question you link to is about **group** homomorphisms.

Ring homomorphisms are additive group homomorphisms which furthermore respect multiplication and map the unit element of one ring to the other. In the case of $\mathbb{Z}$, this clearly forces the image of all other elements as well.

Comment: Wait, does this mean that there is only a single one $\textit{ring}$ homomophism $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: You see, I'm hung up on "unique" here, it clear to me that for any ring $R$, there is a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to R$, but when claimed that it is unique, it sounds to me that there can be only a single possible homo between $\mathbb{Z}$ and any other ring, which doesn't sit right.

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by “doesn’t sit right.” Of course there’s a single homomorphism Z \to Z, the identity. Again, you must map 0->0 and 1->1, so necessarily m->m for all m.

Comment: why doesn't the zero map count?

Comment: You know $0 \rightarrow 0$ (0 maps to the additive identity) and $1 \rightarrow 1$ (1 maps to the multiplicative identity). Then $2$ must map to $1+1$, $3$ must map to $2+1$ etc. and $-1$ must map to the additive inverse of $1$ and so on.

Comment: @gandalf61 Yes, this is clear. I'm now wondering why the edge case of $x \mapsto 0$ for all $x$, which is a homo, doesn't count as a counterexample for uniqueness?

Comment: Julius, this was explained three times already. 1 maps to 1, so the zero map is not a ring homomorphism.

Comment: But it is a homomorphism for the zero ring! Or is this case excluded by "1 as a constant is considered to be part of the structure" as in the answer by Berci?

Comment: And also, accoring to this question, there are more than one homo $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, which brings me back to what "unique" means here. Question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380843/describe-all-ring-homomorphisms

Comment: The constant 1 is part of the structure of commutative rings. The zero "rng" is a rng (ring without unit), not a ring, according to most modern definitions. 

There is a single *unital* ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ as well, I'm not sure which question you are referring to and why you keep bringing up other questions. The proof of the uniqueness is short and clear.

EDIT: Ok, you provided a link to the question. That question does not assume that ring homomorphisms preserve the unit, as explicitly described in the answers.

Comment: @Alon Amit The zero ring has a multiplicative unit, namely the zero itself.

Comment: I did some reading, yeah this unital stuff is superimportant. I understand what you mean now. Actually even in the zero ring, where we take $1 = 0$, it works, in the sense that there is a unique homo $\mathbb{Z} \to \{0\}$ too. And I've convinced myself that for unital ring homos there indeed is only one homo $\mathbb{Z} \to R$ for any unital $R$. Which felt weird but feels better now. Gotta get that spleen onboard, ya know... Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @asdq that’s right. I should have said $1 \neq 0$. At any rate this was not relevant to the main discussion.

Answer (score 0):

There is a unique such homomorphism of '*unital rings*', i.e.  $1$ as a constant is considered to be part of the structure, and hence has to be mapped to $1$ under a ring homomorphism.